# How to open and read text files in a folder python

Tags: python, list, directory

I have a folder which has a text files in it. I want to be able to put in a path to this file and have python go through the folder, open each file and append its content to a list.

```
import os

folderpath = "/Users/myname/Downloads/files/"
inputlst = [os.listdir(folderpath)]
filenamelist = []

for filename in os.listdir(folderpath):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        filenamelist.append(filename)

print(filename list)
```

So far this outputs:

```
['test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt', 'test5.txt', 'test6.txt', 'test7.txt', 'test8.txt', 'test9.txt', 'test10.txt']
```

I want to have the code take each of these files, open them and put all of its content into a single huge list not just print the file name. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to read a list of txt files in a folder in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672809/how-to-read-a-list-of-txt-files-in-a-folder-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does the content look like in the files and how should the result list appear (show small, representative, reproducible snippets)? `inputlst = [os.listdir(folderpath)]` is unused in your code and probably doesn't do what you want (`inputlst = os.listdir(folderpath)` would make more sense).

Answer (score 2):

You should use file **open** for this.
Read here a documentation about its [advanced options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Anyway, here is one way how you can do it:

```py
import os

folderpath = r"yourfolderpath"
inputlst = [os.listdir(folderpath)]
filenamecontent = []

for filename in os.listdir(folderpath):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(os.path.join(folderpath,filename), 'r')
        filenamecontent.append(f.read())

print(filenamecontent)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3, you can use :

```
for filename in filename_list :
    with open(filename,"r") as file_handler :
        data = file_handler.read()
```

Please do mind that you will need the full (either relative or absolute) path to your file in `filename`

This way, your file handler will be automatically closed when you get out of the `with` scope.
More information around here : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#open

On a side note, in order to list files, you might want to have a look to [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html) and use :

```py
filename_list = glob.glob("/path/to/files/*.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fileinput`

***Code:***

```
import fileinput

folderpath = "your_path_to_directory_where_files_are_stored"
file_list = [a for a in os.listdir(folderpath) if a.endswith(".txt")]
# This will return all the files which are in .txt format

get_all_files = fileinput.input(file_list)

with open("alldata.txt", 'ab+') as writefile:
    for line in get_all_files:
        writefile.write(line+'\n')
```

The above code will read all the data from `.txt` from a specified directory(*folderpath*) and store it in *alldata.txt* So, you wanted to have that long list, that list is now stored in .txt file if you want, else you can remove the write process.

***Links:***

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: You probably should use `glob`  instead of `a.endswith(".txt")` since it is more flexible and practical (you can specify the path as a standard unix path pattern and all matching files path will be returned)